# nginx as reverse proxy for hypnotoad

Tags: linux, nginx, centos, reverse-proxy

I have setup an **nginx** server listening on **80**, and a **hypnotoad** server on **8080**.

**Existing**

> example.com = nginx server
>
> example.com:8080 = hypnotoad server

I want to configure nginx as a reverse proxy such that :

**Required**

> example.com = nginx server
>
> example.com/up = hypnotoad server

the **nginx** server is at **/var/www/nginx/public**
and the **hypnotoad** server is at **/var/www/hypnotoad/**

I had tried placing the following at the end of the nginx config in the **sites-available** folder :

```
location / {
proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
}
```

When I visited example.com/up, I was served only text and hyperlinks. **None of the css or the javascripts worked**. When I viewed the source code from the browser, it pointed to the assets of the nginx server and not the hypnotoad server.

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You must specify the different locations in nginx:

```
location /up {
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
}

location / {
  root /var/www/nginx/public;
}
```

Comment: see https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#root-inside-location-block - you should not use root directive inside location block. Define root on the top level and just add location /up definition.